# Disable GUI in Mysql ODBC

Tags: c++, mysql, c, cmake, odbc

I need Mysql-connector-odbc library to include in my project without any need to  GUI. But when I use cmake to configure and then make library, I get error that I have not any gtk or gtk.h installed on my system like this:

```
fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

So, the question is, how to disable GUI in mysql odbc?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some of CMakefiles and Readme files inside the library, I got that the simplest way to disable gui in mysql odbc is using of cmake parameters.
For this, you can just add **DISABLE_GUI** and set it to ***1***. So you disallow Cmake to make GUI and other related library depend on gtk.h header file.
You can see a simple Cmake command to do this:

> cmake -DDISABLE_GUI=1